# making dashed lines darker in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-styles

Hi All: I have this code below that was given to me by someone ( who knows tikzpicture ) a long time ago. It works but now I want the lines to be darker. I've looked around but the tikzpicture  documentation is quite a monster and I have no experience using it so I have no idea how to achieve my goal. If you need the full code in order to help me, I can send that. Thanks a lot.

```
  \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {4.5/01/06,3.5/02/07,2.5/03/08,1.5/04/09,0.5/05/10}
        \draw (-2, \y) node{11:\m\,-\,11:\mm};
```

Oh, I  understand that the y, m and mm are being looped over but I  don't understand the 11:, the - or the other 11:. Also, if someone knows of a good tikzpicture for dummies document that might  help also. I will keep looking around but I've been at this for about half a day and haven't had any luck so far. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks JairoDelRio. I checked the other person's answer but your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The result is a timer

The \y is the coordinate where the time is to be shown on the page

The first time will be place at coord x:y where x is -2, and y is 4.5units

The second time will be place at coord x:y where x is -2, and y is 3.5units, that is 1 unit under the first time or directly below the first time since x remains same but y
decrease by 1 unit from 4.5 to 3.5

The third time will be place at coord x:y where x is -2, and y is 2.5units

The fourth time will be place at coord x:y where x is -2, and y is 1.5units

The `11:` is the hour which remains constant

The `01/06` is the minutes with a `-` in between so this becomes `11:01-11:06` and so on